# React - how to get previous location from React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I have a button, where I should redirect based on the previous location. If the entry exists and it is from the same domain, it should redirect to that last entry, and if not it should redirect to the default page.
Right now, I am just using `history.goBack()` on the button, which means if I am coming to the page from some other website, it will redirect to that website. I would like to avoid that and redirect it the default page. I also need to check if the last entry is from a specific page in my app, because then I would also like to avoid redirecting to it.

```
          <IconButton aria-label="Clear" onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
            <ClearIcon/>
          </IconButton>
```

To manage that I would need access to entries in the history object, but I don't see that in the [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). How can I manage this scenarios with react-router?

Comment: [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history). Treat the history object as an array and you'll get the entire history entries.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by treat the history object as an array?

Comment: `history[x]`? Just judging by the docs.

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: I don't think it's possible from JavaScript to read the browser history, probably for security and privacy reasons. However you could use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) instead which should give you the URL of the previous page that linked to the current page. It seems like that's all you need

Comment: document.refferer is not working either in my react app, it is just giving me current uri, and not the previous one

Comment: I guess because React Router turns your React app into a single page application, so technically you are never really navigating away from the current page. It should still give you the desired behavior. When you navigate to your app from an external domain you should be able to see that in `document.referrer`

Comment: How did you solve this at the end? I am facing the same problem. Thank you and regards